# Create lists with headings and columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using sharepoint 2010. Is it possible to create a list with sections and columns for each sections. E.g.

Section A will have it's own columns
Section B will have it's own columns

so when you add a new item to the list, it would be displayed as

## Section A

## INPUT 1

## INPUT 2

## Section b

## INPUT 1

## INPUT 2

Answer (score 0):

you can define different content types, Section A and Section B. There you define the fields and then add this two content type to a list.
if you filter your view then by content type you will get a view like this.

Here is a reference to content types
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms479905(v=office.14).aspx